# "Seamless" Dual-Boot with Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Having a fast boot time is important to me, and I would like to dual-boot my computer without significantly impacting it. Is it possible to configure grub to instantaneously boot windows unless I hold the "L" key on my keyboard while the computer is booting, in which case it would boot Ubuntu? If it matters, Windows is on a 1TB NVMe SSD and Ubuntu would be installed on a 1TB SATA HDD.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can set the grub timeout to 0

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/timeout.html

> A timeout of ‘0’ means to boot the default entry immediately without displaying the menu

You can also give your Linux `menuentry` in grub a hotkey. See the `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` section

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html

> If a hotkey associated with a menu entry is pressed, it will boot the associated menu entry immediately

However, I'm doubtful the combination would work exactly as you want.  I'd *guess* you would have to hold `ESC` to avoid the automatic boot, and then press your hotkey.

I did some quick tests in a VM.  Adding a `--hotkey=l` option to a menuentry and using the following settings did what you wanted, *except* there is a 1 second delay in booting.

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

I wasn't able to get invoke the grub menu at all when using `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`.  However, the VM boot so fast that it was tough to test.